# Problem with tree and scrollbar tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tree, scrollbar

I'm writing to you because I can't solve this, I need the bar to be on the right of the tree. but there is no way, in which I am wrong, thank you very much to all

```
class Product:
    WIDTH = 500     
    HEIGHT = 500

    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, window):
      
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Aplicación')

        screen_width=self.wind.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height=self.wind.winfo_screenheight()

        x= (screen_width / 2) - (Product.WIDTH /2)
        y= (screen_height / 2) - (Product.HEIGHT /2)

        self.wind.geometry(f"{Product.WIDTH}x{Product.HEIGHT}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
    
        self.wind.resizable(False, False)

        frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.wind, corner_radius=5)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        frame.pack(expand="true")
        

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(master=frame,height = 10, selectmode="browse")
        self.tree.grid(row = 2,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=(10,20))
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Ultimos registros', anchor = CENTER)
     
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame,orient='vertical',command=self.tree.yview)
        scrollbar.grid(row = 2, column=1, sticky="NS",pady=(10,20))

        self.get_fechas()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've added the treeview in column 0 with a columnspan of 2, meaning it will be in columns 0 and 1. You then put the scrollbar in column 1, meaning the two widgets will overlap. If you want the scrollbar to the right, it needs to be at least one column greater than the tree.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the explanation I was able to solve it